# Write way to add samples to torch TabularDataset

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, torch

I have a TabularDataset and i would like to add some examples to the dataset.

```
dataset = TabularDataset(path=path, format="csv", fields=[('label', l_f),('data', d_f)])
# I tried this
dataset.examples = new_examples # new_examples is a list of examples 
len(dataset) == len(new_examples) # This is True
```

I can see that the length of the dataset has changed and in examples i have the examples from new_exampels, but i don't think this is the wright way to do it because i think that it messes up the other methods in TabularDataset.

What is the wright way to add samples or to create a new dataset from a list of examples?